# C# RDLC Expand All / Collapse All SubReport

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using following tools: -

- Visual Studio.NET 2013
- C#
- SQL Server 2014

I have created a report, which contains a sub report. The main report displays the Sale records, while the sub report displays the details of each Sale record (Item details). Each Sale record displays a + sign on the start of the record. User click the + sign and the sub report (details for that specific Sale record) opens.

I want to add a Expand All / Collapse All option to the report.

I have searched a lot but all the articles are related to Groups not to the Sub Reports.

Please tell how to expand/collapse all the records at once.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable a user to interactively expand or collapse report items, or expand or collapse rows and columns associated with a group for a table or matrix. To allow users to expand or collapse an item, you set the visibility properties for that item. Setting visibility works in an HTML report viewer, and is sometimes called a drilldown action.
In report design view, you specify the name of the text box where you want to display the expand and collapse toggle icons. In the rendered report, the text box displays a plus (+) or minus (-) sign in addition to its contents. When the user clicks the toggle, the report display is refreshed to show or hide the report item, based on the current visibility settings for items in the report.
Typically, the expand and collapse action is used to initially display only summary data and to enable the user to click the plus sign to show detail data. For example, you can initially hide a table that displays values for a chart, or hide child groups for a table with nested row or column groups, as in a drilldown report.

To add expand and collapse action to a group
1. In report design view, click the table or matrix to select it. The Grouping pane displays the row and column groups.

[image]

If the Grouping pane does not appear, click the View menu and then click Grouping.

2. Right-click anywhere in the title bar of the Grouping pane, and then click Advanced. The Grouping pane mode toggles to show the underlying display structure for rows and columns on the design surface.
   [image]
3. In the appropriate group pane, click the name of the row group or column group for which you want to hide the associated rows or columns. The group is selected and the Properties pane shows the Tablix Member properties.
4. In Hidden, choose one of the following options to set the visibility of this report item the first time you run a report:
   Select False to display the report item.
   Select True to hide the report item.
   Select  to open the Expression dialog box to create an expression that is evaluated at run time to determine the visibility.
5. In ToggleItem, from the drop-down box, select the name of a text box to which to add the toggle image.
   [image]

In the following image, the Color row group is configured enable users to expand and collapse associated rows.

6. To test the toggle, run the report and click the text box with the toggle image. The report display refreshes to show row groups and column groups with their toggled visibility.

[image]

7. To add expand and collapse action to a report item
   In report design view, right-click the report item to show or hide, and then click  Properties. The  Properties dialog box for the report item opens.
   Click Visibility.
   In When the report is initially run, choose one of the following options to set the visibility of this report item the first time you run a report:
   Select Show to display the report item.
   Select Hide to hide the report item.
   Select Show or hide based on an expression to use an expression evaluated at run time to determine the visibility. Click (fx) to open the Expression dialog box to create an expression.
8. In Display can be toggled by this report item, from the drop-down box, type or select the name of a text box in the report in which to display a toggle image; for example, Textbox1.
   In the following image, the table is configured to enable users to expand and collapse it. The display of the table is toggled by the Products Table text box.

[image]

9. To test the toggle, run the report and click the text box with the toggle image. The report display refreshes to show report items with their toggled visibility.
   [image]

Comment: But this applies to groups. I have asked about Sub Reports. And also I am asking about an "Expand All" / "Collapse All" option, that can expand/collapse all the records of the main report.